# How to handle graphql errors on Apollo server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to handle Graphql errors from Apollo server using Apollo server. My stack look like this.

```
Web Application => Apollo server1(S1) => Apollo server2(S2) => Database
```

Web Application can only connect to S1, S1 works as a proxy that have an authentication with some small logic. All business logic are on S2 which is connected to the Database.

The problem I am trying to handle is when S1 request to S2, but multiple errors occurred in S2. Response that S1 receive will look like this

```
{ data: null, errors: [{ message: "error1"... }, { message: "error2"... }] }
```

So S1 which is work as a proxy should also return error1 and error2 but I can only throw 1 error.

The question is how can I handle multiple Graphql errors in this situation ?

Comment: did you check the formatError of ApolloServer ?

Comment: Yes i did, if I understand correctly formatError works great for format technical language to be readable. But still not help with the case. Thanks you anyway :)

Comment: It's not possible to throw multiple errors in JavaScript. See the linked post for details.